# whenever i try to login my application these sql error 1146 happens. how to solve it?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to build spring boot project.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/INTERNET_BANKING?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=password
```

my `application.properties` file have these settings

```java
@Repository
public interface adminRepository extends CrudRepository<Admins, Long> {
    @Query(value =  "select A_PASSWD from ADMIN where A_ID=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    String checkPasswordById(long id);
}
```

my repository class have this func.

```java
@GetMapping("/logWithID")
    public String returnHomePage(@RequestParam("ID") long id, @RequestParam("passwd") String passwd) {
        if (admrepo.existsById(id)) {
            System.out.println(admrepo.checkPasswordById(id));
            if (admrepo.checkPasswordById(id) == passwd) {
                return "admin";
            }else{
                return "login";
            }
        } else if (cstrepo.existsById(id)) {
            if (cstrepo.checkPasswordById(id) == passwd) {
                return "customer";
            }else{
                return "login";
            }
        }else{
            return "login";
        }
    }
```

my controller class have this func.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADMIN")
public class Admins {
```

my entity class

```
-2020-10-10 22:42:32.482 - INFO 8068 --- [nio-8100-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
-2020-10-10 22:42:32.482 - INFO 8068 --- [nio-8100-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
-2020-10-10 22:42:32.489 - INFO 8068 --- [nio-8100-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
-2020-10-10 22:43:51.754 -DEBUG 8068 --- [nio-8100-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select count(*) as col_0_0_ from admin admins0_ where admins0_.a_id=?
-Hibernate: select count(*) as col_0_0_ from admin admins0_ where admins0_.a_id=?
2020-10-10 22:43:52.085 -DEBUG 8068 --- [nio-8100-exec-4] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select A_PASSWD from ADMIN where A_ID=?
-Hibernate: select A_PASSWD from ADMIN where A_ID=?
2020-10-10 22:43:52.154 - WARN 8068 --- [nio-8100-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
-2020-10-10 22:43:52.154 -ERROR 8068 --- [nio-8100-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Table 'INTERNET_BANKING.ADMIN' doesn't exist
-2020-10-10 22:43:52.245 -ERROR 8068 --- [nio-8100-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
-
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'INTERNET_BANKING.ADMIN' doesn't exist
```

& I'm getting this error.
I dropped my tables & rebuilt them again but the error persist.

Comment: Are you sure the table name is ADMIN not ADMINS? Add the Admins entity class.

Comment: ```@Entity
//@SequenceGenerator(name = "ADM-SEQ", initialValue = 7280, allocationSize = 8000)
@Table(name = "ADMIN")
public class Admins { ||||||||||||||||||||yes i'm sure

Comment: Can you show your database structure in MySQL Workbench or another db tool? Because the error is very clear that it can't find a table INTERNET_BANKING.ADMIN

Comment: plz check the link [ https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Xq9u3u7gX7ZnJjhglMgOyI9B0FrXu4o/view?usp=sharing ]

Comment: @OnurBaştürk are you able to view the image i shared?

Comment: Yeah case sensitivity could be the problem. Just try and check if the error occurs again! That's why I asked for the db schema

Comment: in your query change ADMIN to admin and try again. Where did you install Mysql server ? Windows , Linux or Mac ?

Comment: no @ShawrupKumerSuter i'm using pop os. & thanks everyone it helped